# Cause of Service Control Manager restarting a service

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, proxy, windows-server-2016

Service Control Manager in Windows Server 2016 keeps restarting one of the service every 1 min. How can we find the reason behind service control manager restarting the service?

On checking out the event view I am able to see Event ID 7031 with the below error description:

> service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 1 time(s).  The following corrective action will be taken in 60000 milliseconds: Restart the service.

Comment: The SCM is simply doing its job and the problem is with the service. Are there any errors from the service in the "Application" area in the Event Logs? Do you have access to the code to debug?

Comment: In the events log no application specific errors are reported. No abnormal cpu activity as well. I was just wondering if SCM could give more information on why it decided to restart the service. The details from the error:                                            <Provider Name="Service Control Manager" Guid="{555908d1-a6d7-4695-8e1e-26931d2012f4}" EventSourceName="Service Control Manager" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="49152">7031</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    
    <Channel>System</Channel>

Comment: The SCM doesn't know whey the service failed -- just that it did. You must look to the service (it's logs, etc.) to figure out what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Locate the service (as it is named in the Event description) in Windows services console (Run->Services.msc).

Right-click on the service and go to Properties.

Navigate to the Recovery tab. Here it is defined the action taken (in your case restart the service) when the service terminates unexpectedly as for Event ID 7031